# Sufficient conditions for "hedging" inequality with concave functions:

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $u$ be a real-valued function that is strictly increasing and concave. Let $S\in \mathbb{R}_+$ and $p \in [0,1]$. What are sufficient conditions for the following to hold:

$$p\cdot u\left(\frac{1}{p} + s\right) + (1-p)\cdot u(0) \leq p \cdot u(s) + (1-p) \cdot u\left(\frac{1}{1-p}\right)$$

The idea behind this is to show that an agent might want to hedge by betting against their preferred option, yielding payoff S under certain conditions, which I haven't found.

Thank you for your help!